# How can I use chrome.extension.geturl() method in HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to load a local image from extension. I write the following code to load image. But it can not load image.

```
$('.aAU').append('<div id="DivScroll"><img id="imgSlider" width="25px" src=chrome.extension.getURL("images/slider.png") /></div>');
```

The file is also present at that location.

When I use developer tool it shows img tag as follows

```
<img id="imgSlider" src="chrome.extension.getURL('images/slider.png')">
```

If I use static path such as follows then it display the image

```
<img id="imgSlider" src="chrome-extension://ccpdgakpdgiklccnpnihmidbjnacgkch/images/slider.png">
```

provide any solution to use `chrome.extension.getURL()` method in HTML tags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are your resources registered in manifest file as shown here

```
{
  ...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/my-awesome-image1.png",
    "images/my-amazing-icon1.png",
    "style/double-rainbow.css",
    "script/double-rainbow.js"
  ],
  ...
}
```

These resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL `chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]`, which can be generated with the `chrome.extension.getURL` method.

Did you try to set src to following code through Java Script instead of

> `<img id="imgSlider" src="chrome.extension.getURL('images/slider.png')">`

Comment: Small precision, in v3 `chrome.extension.getURL` becomes `chrome.runtime.getURL`

Answer (score 1):

```
    '<img id="imgSlider" width="25px" src='+chrome.extension.getURL("images/slider.png")+' />'
```

try this it should do the trick